# SQLite sorting question

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I'm using SQLite DB in my Android Application.

There are numbers and strings in a column. Something like:

3, 1, 2, 6 / 6A, X, 3A, 10, 12, XY, 44, ZW

If I select values of this column and sort them, I get:

1, 10, 12, 2, 3, 3A, 44, 6 / 6A, X, XY, ZW

Is there any possibility in **SQLite** to sort these values so, that I would get:

1, 2, 3, 3A, 6 / 6A, 10, 12, 44, X, XY, ZW

Thank you,

Mur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many experiments I've got a proper query:

```
select _id, case 
when cast(_id as number) = 0 then _id
when cast(_id as number) <>0 then cast(_id as number)
end as sorting
from lines
order by sorting
```

The good thing is, that the casting operation returns for '6 / 6A' 6 back.

**UPD**

Don't know why, but if I use this query in my android application, I get _id column as number, so I must do the casting to text

```
select cast(_id as text) as _id, case 
when cast(_id as number) = 0 then _id
when cast(_id as number) <>0 then cast(_id as number)
end as sorting
from lines
order by sorting
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the pure numbers and pure strings as desired simply by storing the numbers as numbers (you are currently storing everything as strings).

The hybrids (`3A` and `6A`) are trickier. One option is to extract the numeric prefix and store that in a sorting column (along with the other values unmodified):

```
original sort
   1      1
   2      2
   6A     6
   6      6
   3A     3
   X      X
   XY     XY
```

Then order by the sorting column followed by the original column:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
 ORDER BY sort, original
```

Comment: do you mean, that I should have differents tables for numbers and strings? and then just use union?!

Comment: No, a single table. SQLite is perfectly happy storing multiple types in a single column.

Comment: sorry, but I'm not sure, I understand you right. Should I change the way of table creating? or can I already use existing data, also if numbers saved as string. Or what did you mean with "storing the numbers as numbers"?

Comment: SQLite is strongly-typed, which means that `12` and `'12'` are different things. The first is a number that will be sorted numerically. The second is a string that will sort alphabetically (i.e., `12` comes after `2`, but `'12'` comes before `'2'`). If you mix these up in a single column and order by that column, all the numbers will come before all the strings. The trick I suggested resolves the problem of ordering things like `'6A'`, which have to be strings, since they contain non-digits, but which you still want to sort numerically.

Comment: A really big thank on you for giving my some ideas. I found my own solution with them, which works really fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solutions of Tima and Marcelo Cantos I found the following solution:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable
 ORDER BY CAST(original AS INTEGER), original;`