# How to sort text naturally with values equaled to 0?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, natural-sort

I'd like to sort this test table from sql:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    val text
);

insert into test (_id, val) values ("49","-10");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("53","-6");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("63","-6");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("9","-5");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("56","-5");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("73","-5");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("38","-4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("52","-4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("55","-4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("64","-4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("81","-4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("50","-3");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("60","-3");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("78","-3");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("27","-2");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("1","80");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("2","85");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("3","100");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("4","120");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("5","-");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("6","0");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("7","0 (init)");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("8","-1");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("23","1");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("67","3");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("14","4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("16","4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("22","4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("61","4");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("37","5");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("51","5");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("76","5");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("32","6");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("35","6");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("71","6");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("88","6");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("18","7");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("44","7");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("39","9");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("90","9");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("91","9");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("69","16");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("105","-");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("36","0");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("65","0");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("75","0");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("106","d");
insert into test (_id, val) values ("43","noise");
```

using modified sql from here:
[SQLite sorting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368864/sqlite-sorting-question)

```
select _id, case when cast(val as number) = 0 then val when cast(val as number) <>0 then cast(val  as number) end as sorting from test order by sorting;
```

i got almost perfect result, but: 0 values are not between positive and negative

Comment: WHich is the sorting column? It helps to see the original data

Comment: Could You check my question after i updated it?

Comment: SQLFiddle to play: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f806e/1

Comment: What's with the rows where `val` is "noise" or "d"? Should they go to the end or be filtered?

Comment: @tombom beginning or end, whatever but not among numeric values

Comment: Note in the original example/edit - the sort column was numeric making it a string gives no benefit to this as as 20 > 10000

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, this is for MySQL. Maybe you can adjust it for SQLite?

May not be the prettiest, but this sorts any "val" which is not a (signed) number to the end. Just make sure it gets a higher value than the highest number.

```
select
  _id,
  val
from test
order by 
case when val NOT REGEXP '^-{0,1}[0-9]{1,}$' then 999999 else
cast(val as signed integer)
end
```